# VS2010 Source Control Explorer (Team Explorer) show new files starting from date

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

I need to find in the solution files created (not modified) after f.e. 10.10.2010.
How can i do that?
I tried to use windows explorer for that, but when getting the files locally their date is "wrong" as for me (date of creation of local copy, not original file)

Comment: Can't you compare the folders using *Source at Date* and *Latest Version* ?

Comment: Wow, amazing, thanks, Dave, it sounds strange, but it turns out
 that i didn't really know how to compare folders there :) can you post this reply as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Source Control Explorer you can compare folders:

[image]

From there, use the **Date** version to specify what you want to compare:

[image]